# ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from firebasestore cloud and I get an error of permission even though I login successfully.

This is the rule in firebasestore (I don`t want open access to anyone in production)

```
match /{document=**} {
    allow read,write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

this is the request:

```
public items: Observable<Doa[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.items = this.db.collection<Doa>('countingData').valueChanges();
        console.log(this.items);
    }
```

I get an error: [image: screenshot]

Comment: Please include any kind of error message as pasted text instead of screenshots whenever possible.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd strongly suggest that you don't include sensitive information such as login credentials, tokens and so on in a public post.